# android appWidget - put my own appWidget without user confirmation

Tags: android, android-activity, click, preview, android-appwidget

Suppose I have an android project which has working appWidget that can be added to the app-launcher.
The project also has an activity that shows the appWidget that I've created.

the probelm: 
For the launcher, the appWidget works perfectly and it responds to user clicks, but for the activity, it is only shown , as if it's a preview .

i've tried (and succeeded) showing other appWidgets , but they are also only being shown . 
however, clicking on buttons seem to have a clicked style effect , as if it might be possible to handle touch events.
note that the appWidget could have extra functionality in the future in addition to user clicks .

Can anyone tell me what can I do in order to handle this issue? Is it even possible to do such a thing, and if not, why (since it's a part of the application) ?
Note that I want to do as little changes to the appWidget as possible, since the appWidget can be a complex one.

here's a snippet for getting the appWidget view in order to show it:

```
public View fetchAppWidgetView(final Context context, final ComponentName componentName)
{
  final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
  _appWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(context, INSTANCES_ID_PROVIDER);
  // get appWidgetInfo :
  final List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> infos = appWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();
  AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = null;
  for (final AppWidgetProviderInfo info:infos)
    if (info.provider.getClassName().equals(componentName.getClassName()) && info.provider.getPackageName().equals(componentName.getPackageName()))
    {
      appWidgetInfo = info;
      break;
    }
  if (appWidgetInfo == null)
    return null;
  final int appWidgetId = _appWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
  // create and put the new widget:
  final AppWidgetHostView newWidget = _appWidgetHost.createView(context, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
  newWidget.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
  _appWidgetHost.startListening();
  return newWidget;
}

public void startListening()
{
  //this method is called on the onStart() method of the activity
  _appWidgetHost.startListening();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for security reasons ok - your app doesnt have permissions to put a app widget
without a users knowledge on a screen. the only ways you have is to let the user pick
the widget from a list, or, your app have to be installed in the /system/app folder and
in this way the app is a system app with all needed permissions.

Comment: even if the appWidget is mine , and even if the appWidget is within the same application? such a thing cannot be because of security measures , no?

Comment: as i wrote, a user have to pick the widget from a pre-defined widget list from the android system or your app is a system app.

A small example: you write a nice app, include a widget and the user installs your app. within the installation process or with first execution of your app your activity installs a widget on the users workspace. and, now its the security problem: your widget reads all the users contacts and sends it to your server - without the knowledge from the user, he/she can do still nothing against your sad app widget.

Comment: please explain more . if i put an appWidget inside my app , it gets only the permissions i give to it , so the user cannot be surprised of an appWidget that uses those permission from within the activity of mine that shows it, since both the activity and the appWidget are a part of the same application.

Comment: i can also see that for some launchers, a few appWidgets show by default . for example on the "go launcher" , the google search appWidget is shown by default. how did they achieve that?

Comment: i think that for the launchers , they use their own views , and not real appWidgets . the only way that an app can put an appWidget without user confirmation is to use it as a system app , which requires a root or just being there from the beginning.